# Combine Python String With Javascript Value

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

```
self.br.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_phMainContent_KeywordForm_ControlPanel_txtKeywords').value = 'keywordurl';")
```

I use selenium in python, I have the following code which executes Javascript. The part of keyworurl is a python string list of around 1300 lines. But when I use that code it will write "keywordurl" and not what the keywordurl represents in python... any ideas? If it was possible to do " + keywordurl + " or something?

Comment: Why wouldn't what you thought of be possible? Seems workable to me. Just take care that `keywordurl` doesn't contain anything that would break the script, i.e. other single quotes. (Better yet, whitelist for characters you expect. That is, unless `keywordurl` doesn't come from an end user.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python string formatting:

```
for keywordurl in open("textfile.txt").readlines():
    self.br.execute_script( "document.getElementById('ctl00_phMainContent_KeywordForm_ControlPanel_txtKeywords').value = '%s';" % keywordurl )
```

The `%s`-specifier is replaced with a string, that follows the  `%`-Operator.

More detailed information: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: Hey koffein thank you! Just to make sure here is how I get my keywordurl read from text file so this should work fine for this method? I also want to keep it the format of the lines so it stays 1300 lines? http://pastebin.com/vJfVy4hk

Comment: Using this code, It looks like it's just 1 line of data + the keywords lines have http:// this seems to mess it up?

Comment: @I can't find the error because the console shows me 1300 lines and can't get back to it with arrow up or anything >.< but the code doesn't work it's bad.

Comment: use less lines in your text file for testing??

Comment: your code only works with 1 line of code. If it's multi line value it doesn't

Comment: update: if writing 1 line with /n it seems to work. Just need to figure how to read many lines and convert it with /n

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do string addition in python :p .
It is better to use str.format though:

```
>>> print "Hello {}!".format("World")
"Hello World!"
```

Since it sounds like you have a list of 1300 strings, it would probably be a good idea to use list.join on it first, to turn it into a giant string.

```
>>> print "".join(["1", "2", "3"])
'123'
```

Comment: @Brospeh I already have a list of my file you can take a look how I retrieve it: http://pastebin.com/vJfVy4hk

Comment: @PeakDermutag what do the lines in your file look like? How do they need to look when they are in your JavaScript code? I'm wondering if there is extra formatting you need to do to your strings before you stuff them into JavaScript.

Comment: @Brospeh the text file looks like http://pastebin.com/L1eaqtCf and I want it to be the same in the javascript value